# Problem when trying to query Long type with Java High Level REST Client

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch Java High Level REST Client, trying to query a document by a Long type value.
I'm trying to search for a document that contains a numeric value: {"productId" : }.
Whenever I search for a int value I get the expected values, but if the number is Long type I always get 0 hits.

I've tried to make the query using MatchQueryBuilder and TermQueryBuilder (I belive TermQueryBuilder is the right option here)

```
SearchSourceBuilder source = new SearchSourceBuilder(); 
SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest(); 
TermQueryBuilder query = new TermQueryBuilder("productId",8317883178163363000L);
source.query(query); 
request.source(source); 
SearchResponse response = this.client.search(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
SearchHits hits = response.getHits();
```

If i search for any value with less than 10 digits (int) i get the expected results. But if I search for anything longer than that I get 0 results.

Comment: You need to check your Elasticsearch index config for that field. If it was created as `integer` then I think Elasticsearch smart enough to understand that your parameter value is too big

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that you have well configured Elastic, and that for each content you perform a good indexing (Elastic has such data)

Try to check the index(document) value,i use a [elastic extension of chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/elasticsearch-head/ffmkiejjmecolpfloofpjologoblkegm), maybe that the value of productId is '8317883178163363000' and not '8317883178163363000L'.
if you haven't a lot of index try to get all y search the value.